# Разные типы параметров у std::ios_base::width и std::setw

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, io

Почему [потоковый width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width) для изменения принимает параметр типа `std::streamsize`, в то время как [манипулятор setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) принимает простой `int`? Насколько я понимаю, они делают одно и то же, а значит, и типы параметров должны быть одни.

Comment: а чья реализация stdlib у вас? в студии 15 setw и width ожидают std::streamsize, который объявлен как long long

Comment: @goldstar_labs g++ с libstd++

Comment: думаю чо-то из них (скорее всего setw) появилось раньше и оставлено для сохранения легаси кода

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у меня есть проект про гидропонику. Для выращивании растений важна температура, и она фигурирует почти везде(например датчики температур). Следовательно я должен выразить что такое температура. Обычно мы выражаем это числом( столько то градусов по цельсий), поэтому я ее без проблем могу определять так(хоть и для тепературы достаточно и байта):

```
using Temperature = long; //мое право
```

а потом написать класс датчика:

```
class Sensor {
    std::vector<Temperature> v;
    Temperature max;
public: 
    //...
    void push(const Temperature t) { v.push_back(t); }
    void set_max_temperature(const Temperature max_t)
    {
        max = max_t;
    }
    //...
};
```

Таким образом я сделал понятным свой код и для себя и для пользователей, что мой класс имеет дело с температурой. Если я вместо `Temperature` использовал 
бы `long`, то никто не понел бы что я имел ввиду(может это количество дырок в кармане или что то еще...).

В файле `<iostream>`, по такой же логике, введен беззнаковый тип std::streamsize. Он может быть определен  например так:

```
using streamsize = long long;
```

А манипулятор потока `setw` определен в другом файле. Это просто функция, возвращающая манипулятор, для которого перегружены операторы ввода и вывода, и она может принимать любой тип, который без потери может неявно преобразоваться в std::streamsize. Это может быть в том числе  и `int`, постольку поскольку в манипулятор мы передает количество... Но, насколько я знаю, она принимает какраз таки `std::streamsize`, просто мы можем спокойно туда передать любой целочисленный тип, в том числе и `int`

Answer (score -1):

это ошибка cppreference на деле везде streamsize

Comment: В [стандарте](http://eel.is/c++draft/std.manip#7) - `int`.